# Using fusion table to feed a line chart

Tags: google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

I have a table which stores events in the form of DATETIME (Eg. 01-01-1970) and TIMESTAMP columns.

When I want to make a query to see the number of events per day, I do something like this:

```
SELECT date, COUNT() FROM tableId GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC
```

which returns data like this:

```
date    count() 
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       3
5       1
6       1
7       1
8       4
9       4
10      3
```

Now I'd like to use this data to draw a line chart:

```
google.visualization.drawChart({
   "containerId": "report",
   "dataSourceUrl": "http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=",
   "query":"SELECT date, COUNT() FROM tableId GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC",
//       "chartType": "Table",
   "chartType": "LineChart",
   "options": {
      "enableInteractivity": false,
      "showRowNumber" : true,
      "vAxis": { "title": "Events" },
      "hAxis": { "title": "Days" }
   }
});
```

But for some reason it doesn't seem to work, as the chart is shown but no data is drawn.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it's because you aren't actually saving anything as a [DataTable object](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable). You can look at the [query language reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#queryobjects) to get an idea of how queries work as sources for Google Visualization objects.

If you look at [this example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#data_source_request) of how to handle a query, then you will see that you need to save the query response and feed that in to your chart as a DataTable object:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // To see the data that this visualization uses, browse to
  // http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ&range=B1:D11&pub=1');

  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  visualization = new google.visualization.IntensityMap(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  visualization.draw(data, null);
}
```

So make sure that you have an intermediate step where you save the result of your query as a DataTable object using `queryResponse.getDataTable()`, and that may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I'm not sure this is the problem. For instance, if you use "Table" chartType then the chart is drawn correctly. Also, if I change the sql query to something like selecting timestamp (which is another column in my fusion table) then a chart is drawn, although showing a monotonically increasing line (as expected, as timestamps are meant to grow as dates increase)

What I mean is that, if these cases work then wouldn't that mean the problem could be somewhere else instead of being about DataTable?

Comment: It would appear so -- since we don't have access to your fusion table, it's a bit tough to test. I was assuming incorrectly what the problem was -- apologies!